# How can I define type for dynamic `this` value in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Given this code for example:

```
async function forEachAsync<T>(
    iterable: T[],
    callback: (this: typeof context, currentValue: T, index: number, array: typeof iterable) => void | Promise<void>,
    context?: any
){
  const { length } = iterable;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++){
    await callback.call(context, iterable[i], i, iterable);
  }
}
```

The type of `this` of the callback function will always be `any`, so it does not perform any checks on its property. For example, the code below should have failed type check for `.charAt` property but couldn't because it has type `any`:

```
forEachAsync([1, 2, 3], function(){
  console.log(this.charAt);  // Should fail type check but couldn't
}, window);
```

To make type checking of `this` possible, I tried the following:

```
async function forEachAsync<T, C = any>(
    iterable: T[],
    callback: (this: typeof context, currentValue: T, index: number, array: typeof iterable) => void | Promise<void>,
    context?: C
){
  const { length } = iterable;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++){
    await callback.call(context, iterable[i], i, iterable);
  }
}
```

Now, when call the function, the type validation works. However, another error occurs:

```
forEachAsync([1, 2, 3], function(){
  console.log(this.charAt);
  // Error: Object is possibly undefined.
  // [expected] Error: Property 'charAt' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'
}, window);
```

**Question**

How can I properly define the type for `context` and `this` to be the same while keeping `context` an optional parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads), one with `context` and another without:

```
async function forEachAsync<T>(
    iterable: T[],
    callback: (this: Window, currentValue: T, index: number, array: typeof iterable) => void | Promise<void>,
): Promise<void>
async function forEachAsync<T, C>(
    iterable: T[],
    callback: (this: C, currentValue: T, index: number, array: typeof iterable) => void | Promise<void>,
    context: C
): Promise<void>
async function forEachAsync<T, C>(
    iterable: T[],
    callback: (currentValue: T, index: number, array: typeof iterable) => void | Promise<void>,
    context?: C
): Promise<void>
{
  const { length } = iterable;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++){
    await callback.call(context, iterable[i], i, iterable);
  }
}

forEachAsync([1, 2, 3], function(){
  console.log(this.charAt); // Property 'charAt' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'
}, window);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsL3QJwKLBQAWAguNADwAqAfABQBQMMqyApjsAEYA2bAXDCoBtALoAaJjCjAePLoQDWgusiKoQggOqoIAE3QB3cdIQ4cbCMgBqshAKEndetgA9BEBAFsuHE8HNgMEFkMAAHNnQ4FnZOXjYAShgAXhoYADd0VD0YAB8YAAUcdC8NNgpM7JpJBMEikrKKrL0aBlBIWEQUDCw4XAJiMg7qEwBheilWDm4+QREJKRk5BShlGFV1TRhRkygzCytbHns5p303D29fHH9A4JhQiKiY6fik1IzmvMLi0pByyotSTMKCYdiuZCCUYMWo-Br-JpVNrkTpIKBoTDYfCEUgokbbCbMKZxWZCMTA6SyeRKFR7cyWGx2BxUM4udwwTw+PwwAKce6PSLRYkzRIpNKA771P4A5rVRZgtzIAD8UJhdV+jUBaQA3vKICBkDBtTA+BAAOZqGAAXxSLxJbAA3FI+jh1nxDahbQAGB0sGAUE2WC1EX2oADUYaSuuYzGAhmArEpyyUADoljw6KCrIqnLERcJUBIWLnXnwEk7mFaGFWGC6BriOnRhABGEwAJhMAGYi110T11lG9SB0HwUzx0GaNho00QAiRkOWYAB6JdwiI4UIwADkxDnyC3MAMbBAHPQhrcGkNmIF250+iMMAAZA9woKYGbxwoeFRNlvqyZDGcIxyyAA)